# $_GET not display character like &

Tags: php, php-7

i tried to create a script to redirect link of amazon, but when pass the link in a get variable url not return Url after the character &, i tried to echo the variable $_GET['tolink'] but display a cut url, my code:

`$url = $_GET['tolink']; header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");  header("Location: $url");`

when pass the url in a variable thi code redirect to :

```
https://www.amazon.com/SAMSUNG-50-Inch-Crystal-AU8000-Built/dp/B08Z1RN7NP/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=samsung%20tv
```

intestead to

`https://www.amazon.com/SAMSUNG-50-Inch-Crystal-AU8000-Built/dp/B08Z1RN7NP/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=samsung+tv&qid=1685363216&sr=8-2`

i tried also just to `var_dump( $_GET['tolink'])` and echo cut url, why ?

**UPDATE:** found a solution, use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` intestead `$_GET['tolink']` it's works but is a safe solution ?

Comment: If your URL contains another URL inside `tolink`, you must URL encode that variable, otherwise it will cut as you describe

Comment: How **exactly** do you pass the URL? As this is tagged with PHP 7 specifically: are you sure this only happens in PHP 7, and not in other versions? Also, when you dump the variable, what happens?

Comment: @NicoHaase, example of a link mydomain.com/redirect.php?tolink=https://www.amazon.com/SAMSUNG-50-Inch-Crystal-AU8000-Built/dp/B08Z1RN7NP/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=samsung+tv&qid=1685363216&sr=8-2 , yes i use php7, when dump the variable a isee the cut verison of url where the caracther after & not appears

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. The URL you've shared does not match the URL from your question, and it doesn't even contain any `&`

Comment: @NicoHaase it as 2 & caracther in link below

Comment: Add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. The comment shows a `tolink` parameter that does not use any ampersands, and it doesn't even start with `https://www` like the URL from your question

Comment: Where exactly are you creating that URL? Where are you putting the Amazon URL into a query parameter? You need to properly URL-encode the value at that point.

Comment: Hello! It sounds like you'd like to pass the Query String you receive in the 301 redirect. Your problem is that the `&` you were given is not being included when you construct the url. As you've discovered `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` will usually contain the query string given. However, for cases where I want to re-pass a query string via php I like to use [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). In this case `http_build_query($_GET)` will take the given query string and re-encode it.

Answer (score 2):

A URL may have parameters, like

**theurl?param1=val1&param2=val2**

so, if you have `&` inside the value of your URL parameter, it is being mistaken for the separator between URL parameters and this is why it is being cut.

If your URL's `tolink` parameter was defined in your PHP code, then you can use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), like this

```
<?php
echo '<a href="someurl?tolink=', urlencode($thelink), '">';
?>
```

Otherwise, if it was defined at your Javascript code, then you can use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), like this:

```
var url = `someurl?tolink=${encodeURIComponent(thelink)}`;
```

If you hard-coded it, then replace the `&` with **%26**.

EDIT

Based on the discussion in the comment-section it looks like there was not much that could be done with the parameter definition, as it was defined somewhere else and, as a result a broken link was received. Hence, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` helped in solving the issue, as that contained the full query string.

Comment: the URL's tolink parameter are not definited in my code and i can't touch it how is composed, this is why i have pass in some way the link like the example

Comment: @gassiopea Then you're getting a *broken* URL which has been improperly put together. Look into `$_SERVER` to find the original unaltered request URL, and process it yourself from there.

Comment: @deceze yes right, i have found some minutes ago the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] string and seems this solve my problem

Answer (score -1):

**1. Use urlencode() when passing the URL as a parameter:**

```
$amazonURL= 'your_amazon_url_here';

$encodedURL = urlencode($amazonURL);

// then you can use $encodedURL as a parameter
```

**2. Use urldecode() when using the URL:**

```
$url = urldecode($_GET['tolink']);

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 

header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: You do *not* need to `urldecode` a value obtained from `$_GET`; those values are already parsed and decoded.

Comment: i have already tried this not work, the url are cut i dont know why

Comment: @deceze yes maybe this is the problem, are alredy parsed, how avoid this ?

Comment: @gassiopea No. The issue is in the code that does `'...?tolink=' . $amazon_url` somewhere. Since you have not shown this code, we can only speculate.